How to control the generated filename when generating OpenAPI specification at build time from the code in ASP.NET Core
I followed the steps that are stated in this blogpost https://www.meziantou.net/generate-openapi-specification-at-build-time-from-the-code-in-asp-net-core.htm
dotnet new webapi --framework net8.0
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server

<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>

    <OpenApiDocumentsDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</OpenApiDocumentsDirectory>
    <OpenApiGenerateDocuments>true</OpenApiGenerateDocuments>
    <OpenApiGenerateDocumentsOnBuild>true</OpenApiGenerateDocumentsOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="8.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.ApiDescription.Server" Version="8.0.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

When you have multiple versions, this will generate files like SampleWebApi.json and SampleWebApi_v2.json.
Is it possible to change this behavior so it will always include the version, or change the template?
So you get SampleWebApi_v1.json and SampleWebApi_v2.json
Or change template so it will be SampleWebApi.v1.json and SampleWebApi.v2.json
I searched for documentation but didn't find anything. Neither changing the value in <OpenApiDocumentsDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</OpenApiDocumentsDirectory> helped.

It only appears to miss the version off when the version matches 'v1', with a lower case 'v', if you use an upper case 'V' it gets appended, so if you are able to update the casing you can use that as a workaround.
I've raised a feature request to update the behaviour in the future.

Can you please share the link to the feature request so we can plus it or vote on it? Changing to capital V is not desirable from an esthetic point of view, but thanks for the suggestion. It may help others.

No worries @Wesley - it's at: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/58782

You could rename the OpenApi file name like below:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <OpenApiDocumentsDirectory>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</OpenApiDocumentsDirectory>
    <OpenApiGenerateDocuments>true</OpenApiGenerateDocuments>
    <OpenApiGenerateDocumentsOnBuild>true</OpenApiGenerateDocumentsOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    //...
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Custom MSBuild target to rename generated OpenAPI documents -->
  <Target Name="RenameOpenApiDocuments" AfterTargets="GenerateOpenApiDocuments">
    <!-- Get the list of generated OpenAPI files -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <GeneratedOpenApiFiles Include="$(OpenApiDocumentsDirectory)\*.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Rename each file to include a version suffix -->
    <Exec Command="for %%f in (@(GeneratedOpenApiFiles->'%(FullPath)')) do (if %%~nxf==SampleWebApi.json ren %%f SampleWebApi_v1.json)" />
    <Exec Command="for %%f in (@(GeneratedOpenApiFiles->'%(FullPath)')) do (if %%~nxf==SampleWebApi_v2.json ren %%f SampleWebApi_v2.json)" />
  </Target>
</Project>

Note: The Exec command in the example uses a batch script (for %%f in...) to rename files. This is specific to Windows. For cross-platform compatibility, you may need to adjust the script accordingly (e.g., using a shell script for Linux/Mac)

I was looking for a solution in configuration rather than executing an additional command, but appreciate your time and quick response to help me solve the inconsistency.
